# How to partition table by date in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

My table `AA` has a document date filed and values format is `2013-08-01 00:00:00.000`. When I try to partition table by date manually in SSMS, row counts are returned incorrectly. Please to clear for me what I m wrong.

[image]

I have total row count of 6876. For 2013 row count is 671, 2014 row count is 5954 and 2015 rows count is 251. Why does the picture rows count show incorrectly?

Comment: What **datatype** is your `document date filed` column??

Comment: @marc_s ,  document date filed is datetime datatype

Comment: Try using the ISO-8601 format for dates : `YYYYMMDD` - so try using `20131231` and `20141231` for your boundaries